# jQuery active class on sub menu accordian

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation

I have been having trouble with adding a separate active class to the sub menu of this vertical accordion menu.

So basically what should be happening is that when you click on the sub menu item the 'li' background should appear blue.

http://jsfiddle.net/tebrown/fadptmsu/

```
var checkCookie = $.cookie("nav-item");
if (checkCookie != "") {
$('#cssmenu > li > a:eq('+checkCookie+')').addClass('active').next().show();
}

$('#cssmenu > li > ul > li > a').click(function(){
var checkElement = $(this).next();
$(this).removeClass('testing');
$(this).closest('li').addClass('testing');  

});

$('#cssmenu > li > a').click(function(){

  var navIndex = $('#cssmenu > li > a').index(this);
  $.cookie("nav-item", navIndex);
  $('#cssmenu li ul').slideUp();
   if ($(this).next().is(":visible")){


       $(this).next().slideUp();
   } else {
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
   }
   $('#cssmenu li a').removeClass('active');

   $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

If anyone could help me out with this that would be great :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding the class active to the submenu

```
$('#cssmenu > li > ul > li > a').click(function () {
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    $(this).removeClass('testing');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('testing');
    $('#cssmenu li li .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/47wxp9a1/)

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! @Arun P Johny - how can i make it so that it saves as a cookie so that it remembers the active state? I have done this for the parent li but would like it to work for the sub menu part too. Cheers.

Comment: @user1628845 you can do it in the very same way, using another cookie key. For example, `$.cookie("sub_nav-item");`

Comment: So pretty much duplicate what they have already done for the $.cookie("nav-item"); ?

Comment: @user1628845 yes. Take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47wxp9a1/3/).

Comment: @Regent great help thanks! - Now I just need to work on + and - icons for when the parent li classes are active.

Comment: @user1628845 you're welcome. Don't forget to mark answer as correct one. And one more thing: if you will have a lot of cookie keys, try to redo their loading (on page loading) into the loop, so that there will not be a lot of duplicating code.

Comment: @DOCASAREL are you talking about `$.cookie`? In modern browsers it will be better to save local browser data using `localStorage`.

Comment: @Regent Did actually not know one can retrieve and set cookies with JS at all. But `localStorage` of course. Never thought of making a state retain after reload anyway.

Comment: How would I use localstorage?

Answer (score 1):

You had an I guess typo in your `:active`.

**Wrong CSS:**

```
#cssmenu li ul li a.active { background-color: blue; }
```

**Right CSS:**

```
#cssmenu li ul li a:active { background-color: blue; }
```

[**JSFIDDLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/fadptmsu/1/)

Comment: Classes are selected using `.className`, aren't they? `:something` is used for another purposes.

Comment: @Regent Yep, but there is no class `active` in the HTML. I guess the OP wanted that, because he said "on click"...?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. DOC how do I make it stay blue?

Comment: Take a look at this lines: `$('#cssmenu li a').removeClass('active');` and `$(this).addClass('active');`

Comment: Take upon the answer by Arun P Johny. I will change the fiddle.

Comment: Basically I want it to do the same as the parent active class. So it will give it a background color + it will save it as a session class. Any help would be great. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code for your click handler.

```
$('#cssmenu > li > ul > li > a').click(function(){
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    // find the closest li
    var liObj = $(this).closest('li');
    // remove any active class that has already been added for other li
    liObj.siblings().find("a").removeClass("active");
    // add active class to current anchor
    liObj.find("a").addClass("active"); 
});
```

@regent Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `liObj.siblings().each(function() { $(this).find("a").removeClass("active"); });` can be simplified into `liObj.siblings().find("a").removeClass("active");`